# .\classes\Student.java:5: error: cannot access IStudentOperations public class Student implements IStudentOperations

Tags: java

What is this problem? I don't solve this problem.

```
.\classes\Student.java:5: error: cannot access IStudentOperations
public class Student implements IStudentOperations
                                ^
  bad source file: .\interfaces\IStudentOperations.java
    file does not contain class interfaces.IStudentOperations
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
```

Comment: You need to tell us how you are compiling (the command you're using), and where your files actually are in the source tree. The error message is a big clue that one of those two things is probably not correct. But without knowing either, it's hard to say which.

Comment: Hello Israfii. Welcome to Stackoverflow, this is great site and I have found a lot of answer on it. If you want that somebody answer your question, please, take more time to explain your problem, use {} to format code. Press New-Line or use <br> html tag so that your text is more readable. Change the title, because I don't understand anything to your problem. I know that it is new for your, but try what I propose.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch sir, actually I use { javac Mycode.java } for compile and Run {Java Mycode.java} .

Comment: Ok. What is "IStudentOperations" - do you have a `.java` file for that? Or do you have a `.class` file? Also, **edit** your question. Don't answer in the comments, not everyone reads them.